# Only first value in android grid view is being returned

Tags: android, gridview, android-edittext

I have a grid view filled with edittexts. When the user presses a button, I want to retrieve all the values stored in the edittexts, but I am only getting the first one back.

The grid view is in the fragment_score.xml.

The edit texts in the grid view grid_items.xml

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_edit_text_red"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"


    />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_edit_text_blue"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

     />
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;

import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

public class RedFragment extends SherlockFragment {


LayoutInflater infl;
GridView mGrid;

String[] etCollection = new String[9];


ImageAdapter adapter;

View mView;


Context mContext;
Button calc;    

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    System.out.println("onCreateView called");
    infl = inflater;
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_score, container, false);
    mGrid = (GridView) mView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewRed);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    //tView = container.getRootView();
    mContext = mView.getContext();

    for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
    {
        etCollection[j] = "-1";
    }




    adapter = new ImageAdapter(mContext);
    mGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.e("debug", "here2");
    calc = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.calc_red);

    calc.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            calculate();
            return true;

        }
    });


    return mView;
}







public void getGridVals(){

    Log.v("vals", "Getting grid Vals()");

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        EditText tempText1 = (EditText)mView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_edit_text_red);
        Log.v("temp text ", "." + tempText1.getText().toString());
                   //this should update etCollection[]
        adapter.getView(i, mView, null);
           //this always prints the value stored in the first textview
        Log.d("etCollection", etCollection[i]);



    }



}

public void setGridVals(int i, String val){

    etCollection[i] = val;


}


public void calculate(){ 
    int[][] pegs = new int[3][3];
    getGridVals();
}



public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;




    public ImageAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        etCollection  = new String[getCount()];

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View myView = convertView;


        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater li = infl;
            myView= li.inflate(R.layout.grid_items, null);


        }
            ///////////////////////////////
        //this seems to always return the value in the first R.id.grid_item_edit_text_red
        EditText editText = (EditText) myView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_edit_text_red);
        etCollection[position] = editText.getText().toString();

        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 9;
    }



    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        Log.w("etCollection: " + position , etCollection[position]);
        return etCollection[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;//mGrid.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using text watchers on the edit texts and updating the arrays from there

Answer (score 0):

I'm still somewhat of an Android newbie but I think you're supposed to have an id for each EditText and you've only defined 2.
So when you do `(EditText)mView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_edit_text_red)` it will return the same EditText every time.
This might help a bit: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Actually for a gridview, you don't need to, but i'm not getting the values properly

Answer (score 0):

There is the problem in the getview method...
as u had used the layout inflator to inflate the editText to get the string
But u need to know that which editText is containing the data

Go for the for loop statement to get the all string.

Run the for loop as number of editText used in view..
for loop

(if edittext.gettext().length()>0)
String data = edittext.gettext();